# Search using ActiveRecord with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to search through a table with multiple conditions given in an array.

I have an array like this

```
[{u_id: 4, lv: 2}, {u_id: 10, lv: 1}, {u_id: 11, lv: 3}, ...]
```

and a table like this.

```
==== User Levels Table ====
| id | u_id | lv | desc |
| 1  | 1    | 1  | hoge |
| 2  | 1    | 2  | moke |
| 3  | 2    | 1  | doge |
...
```

I tried the following code for testing, and I got the results that I wanted.

```
user_levels = UserLevel.where({u_id: 4, lv: 2})
  .or(UserLevel.where({u_id: 10, lv: 1})
  .or(UserLevel.where({u_id: 11, lv: 3}) ...
```

However, I do not know the length of the array, nor the values inside the hash, which means that I cannot hard-code like the last code above.

Is there any idea?

Comment: Look into the map function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is for the array of conditions to be mapped to relations that we can join together with `or` in a reduce block:

```
array_of_conditions = [{u_id: 4, lv: 2}....]
user_levels = array_of_conditions.map {|cond| UserLevel.where(cond)}.reduce {|memo, cond| memo.or(cond)}
```

Comment: You could remove usage of map as well. `array_of_conditions.reduce(UserLevel.where(id: [])) { |query, condition| query.or(UserLevel.where(condition)) }`